# How to Interact with tables in mysql using php.

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database. I use the first one for carrying out the login/registration process where I store the user info (Name , Email , Password). So , I created the second table where the registered users can add product image and name to but I found out that the 2 tables can't interact and there is no way for them to use the second table.

Please , how can I do this ?

If you need more info let me know.

Comment: means you need to `join` them or something else.....

Comment: Read about MySQL joins.

Comment: A decent place to start: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: did you have any relationship between both table like id columns or used id columns on both table . you can procede with mysql JOINS , FULL OUTER JOIN etc...

Comment: @Adetona77. I have provided with clear explanations about the Foreign key and Join Tables. Share thought about your view. if you face any hindrance let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of the `foreign key relationships`.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

- First you have to create the table with the relational ID(Foreign Key) from the First Table so that you can fetch the data.
- After you provide the Foreign key to the Queries where you can use the Joins that are available and you can get the data.

> **Note:** Unless you have the relational ID of the other table you are not advised to use the JOIN Query since you have to pass the Relational ID(Foreign KEY) Over to the join stmt.

SQL statement for Creating the Foreign Key ID From the First Table itself.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

The following SQL creates a FOREIGN KEY on the "P_Id" column when the "Orders" table is created

After Creating the Foreign Key to both the tables that you create you can follow up the code over here and then you can join both the tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

> You have to create the Table Structure like this:

**User Info Table:**

```
+------------------------------------------+
| id   |   name   |   Email   |  Password  |    
+------------------------------------------+
```

And the **Product** table like this

```
+------------------------------------------+
| id   |   user_id   |   product_name      |    
+------------------------------------------+
```

- Here the `user_id` will act as the foreign for the `user` table when accessing the product table.

Hence the Code will be as follows.

**To fetch all the data from two tables:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user JOIN product ON user.id = product.user_id ORDER BY user.id DESC"
```

**To fetch the data based on particular user.**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user JOIN product ON user.id = product.user_id WHERE user.id ='".$id."'"
```

- Where `$id` is the ID of the Current User.

Hope so my explanations will be clear and it will help you a lot.

Happy Coding:)

Comment: Naresh , my questions.

Comment: 1. Am I going to provide foreign keys to both tables.

Comment: Use the user id in both the tables as foreign keys. This will help to create relationship like one-to-many and for joining too. Without those, you may never know who adds images for products.

Comment: In the table "Persons" am I going to create another another foreign key ?

Comment: Hey Naresh , How do I make the user to insert into "product_name" ?

Comment: You have to make some image uploader like such things and handle that part after the user is registered.